# Babel module resolver not working with react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, babeljs

My babel module resolver is not working with React-Native (neither does intellij in VScode)

Here, Is my babel config

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['./'],
        alias: {
          '@assets': './src/assets',
          '@modules': './src/modules',
          '@config': './src/config',
          '@utils': './src/utils',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

And jsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "paths": {
            "@assets": ["./assets"],
            "@modules": ["./modules"],
            "@config": ["./config"],
            "@utils": ["./utils"]
        }
    }
}
```

I changed import for one of my files and this is the error I get when I executed the build command from Xcode

> Error: Error loading assets JSON from Metro. Ensure you've followed
> all expo-updates installation steps correctly. Unable to resolve
> module `../../modules/store/components/Filters` from
> `src/utils/Router.js`:
>
> None of these files exist:

Where I imported the file like this

```
import Filters from '@modules/store/components/Filters';
```

Comment: You just forgot extensions

Answer (score 17):

Try resetting the cache, if above suggested answers don't work

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

This worked for me. For more info see [here](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver/issues/354#issuecomment-475858527)

Comment: An hour spent trawling Stackoverflow reading the same answers and this was the solution.

Comment: bruh, so, basically my config was right from the start.... Man, this is disgusting -_-
Thank you a lot <3

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, I just removed the '@' from my aliases and it seems working fine now.

Here is my babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function (api) {     ■ File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES6 module.   
api.cache(true);                                                                                                
return {                                                                                           
  presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],                                                                                                                             
  plugins: [                                                                                                                                                  
    [                                                                                                                                                         
      require.resolve("babel-plugin-module-resolver"),                                                                                                        
      {                                                                                                                                                
        root: ["./src/"],                                                                                                                              
        alias: {                                                                                                                                       
          // define aliases to shorten the import paths                                                                                                
          components: "./src/components",                                                                                                              
          containers: "./src/containers",                                                                                                              
          contexts: "./src/contexts",                                                                                                                  
          interfaces: "./src/interfaces",                                                                                                              
          organizer: "./src/screens/organizer",                                                                                                        
          screens: "./src/screens",                                                                                                                    
        },                                                                                                                                             
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".tsx", ".ios.js", ".android.js"],                                                                                        
      },                                                                                                                                                      
    ],                                                                                                                                                 
  ],                                                                                                                                                   
};
```

};

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it installing the dev dependencies with:

```
yarn install --dev 

npm install --dev
```

I believe than in most of the cases nothing else is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `module-resolver`'s root to `['./src/']`:

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['./src/'], // <-- here ✅
        alias: {
          '@assets': './src/assets',
          '@modules': './src/modules',
          '@config': './src/config',
          '@utils': './src/utils',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the extensions parameter,

But for the case where the Metro server is enabled, I don't know how to choose between IOS in front or Android in front

```js
{
// http://localhost:8081/foo/bar/baz.bundle?dev=true&platform=ios
extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".tsx", ".ios.js", ".android.js"],
// http://localhost:8081/foo/bar/baz.bundle?dev=true&platform=android
extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".tsx", ".android.js", ".ios.js"],
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issues with babel that I resolved by updating to the node version required by the project and reinstalling everything else: watchman, react-native-cli, node modules and pods.